# On Topic - fixing a drill press?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

The question would include pictures and be:

> My drill press chuck fell out on me while using a 4.5" hole saw bit. It appears to have wobbled itself out because there is some chipping on the tenon on both sides. I plan on attempting a cleaning, filing down where the chips came up, and reseating it. But, I have to ask, because of the chips, is it now junked?

Anyway, that's the question to be. Would that be on topic here or possibly a better fit for woodworking?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It would definitely be on-topic: we have several questions about repairing [tools](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btools%5D%20%5Brepair%5D%20is%3Aq) or [powertools](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpowertools%5D%20%5Brepair%5D%20is%3Aq) already (there's some overlap in the queries because there are a few questions with both tags) and several more about [drill presses](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22drill%20press%22%20is%3Aq).

I'd also say that it's more appropriate for [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) than for [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) because a drill press can be used on other materials than just wood, e.g. metal, tile, stone.

Be sure to include the make and model number of your drill press and photos are always welcome!